# Module, Process, and Thread?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-ce

I am curious about the terminology used in embedded firmware design. I am currently working on a project that uses WinCE 7. Studying the existing code, I've gone through multiple high and low level documents talking about modules, processes, and threads. I decided to do some research to be able to relate the definitions to the existing code architecture.

What I do understand (or think i understand) is that threads are sub-processes of a process, i.e. a process is made up of threads or light-weight processes. The functionality of a process is that of clicking on an the microsoft word icon and the respective threads execute as needed to perform the process. A thread is a small, focused process which takes care of a specific part of the main process. Correct me if i am wrong in my understanding of threads and processes.

Where i am lost is with the difference between processes and modules. If processes are the execution of threads required to perform a task, such as clicking on the MS Word icon, then what is a module?

The way they have described the firmware is by saying something along the lines of: "The system architecture will consist of 7 modules. Each module is responsible for a certain functionality such as data storage, data processing, user interface, etc...". From that, i gather that these "modules" that are listed under the Subprojects folder of my visual studio project are the high level system design, each containing subfiles (.cpp/.h) which make up the processes and inside these processes are the threads (functions/classes, etc..). Is my understanding correct?

Thanks in advance and sorry for the long question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be trying to describe processes and threads in terms of particular usages. E.g. "The functionality of a process is that of clicking on an the microsoft word icon" and "A thread is a small, focused process which takes care of a specific part of the main process."

A process is basically a collection of resources needed to execute code. A process will have things like memory, a handle to a file that contains code to be executed, and also 'threads'. A thread is the thing that actually does the execution, using the other resources the process has.

When you run a program, the OS creates a process with a thread and other resources, and starts that thread executing the desired code at a particular entry point in the code. From that point on the program has responsibility for what it does in terms of what functions it calls or what objects it creates. It can even send messages back to the OS to ask the OS to start more threads, or even completely separate processes, with parameters specified by the original code.

For more details you can see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) or you might want to just grab a textbook on operating systems.

---

The term 'Modules', as you're using it, doesn't have a particularly rigid definition. It is simply a unit of program organization. The program's architect or developers are responsible for deciding what that means for their program, based on how they want the project to be organized and how they want the components to inter-operate. Think of a module as being a like a function or class in terms of helping to organize code, one an additional step higher than those other organizational features, and not necessarily built into the language syntax like classes or functions.

Nor is there any fixed relationship between a project's units of organization (modules, classes, functions, etc.), and processes and threads. A program can contrive to execute whichever of its code it likes using any arrangement of processes and threads it feels is best suited to it.

For example, the program might be designed so that it starts up one thread for each module and has those threads each run a particular 'main' function from that module. Then the modules are designed to inter-operate by passing messages between their threads. Or another example, the program might set up a shared pool of threads for all modules to access and use as needed.

How modules share execution resources (processes and threads) and communicate with each other is entirely up to the designers of the project. The details should be documented, though the documentation is likely to written assuming a reader who is familiar with the common patterns. Since you're not familiar with those patterns you'll probably need to get help from the other devs.

Answer (score 2):

A process on Windows CE (and in Windows in general) is a private address space for an application.
A thread is an execution flow. You may have multiple threads inside a process and the main thread determines process lifetime. If you exit from it (WinMain function), the process is closed and all resources assigned to it are released.
A module is a binary file containing code that is currently loaded in memory. It may be an exe file (used to start a process) or a dynamic link library (dll).

Answer (score 1):

Module can have multiple meanings, which generically means some type of software component, which in some cases is just a file, which could be a source file or an executable file, or a collection of files, perhaps all the files in a folder. Another usage for the term modules refers to "modular" programming, where modules are functions or a collection of functions, which seems to fit with your example of a device composed of 7 modules.

For Windows in general, each process has it's own (virtual) memory space, while threads share the common (virtual) memory space of a process. In the case of embedded systems that only have a flat physical address space (no virtual memory), the main distinction is that processes are launched, and in turn those processes launch threads. For some embedded systems, the older term multi-tasking is sometimes used to describe software, especially in devices like hard drives, where the main part of the multi-tasking software is started up at boot time (some diagnostic software can be dynamically loaded from protected areas of the hard drive and run as needed).

Comment: So, you're saying that the 7 subproject "modules" contain files/functions used to perform the overall task of the specific subproject and that these files/functions are the processes/threads?

I ask this question because one of the documents refers to a "Trigger module", but this module is not a subproject. There are files within the subprojects to implement this trigger functionality, but it is not its own project. So the term module is referring to the collection of functions required to complete the intended operation and is independent of files?

Comment: As mentioned, module can have multiple meanings. Wiki link: [Module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(disambiguation)) .